# PHP page level variables

Tags: php, wordpress, scope

Not much of a PHP programmer, so I have a quick question in order to improve the performance of a WP site.

For many pages, the header and the body are handled by a set of completely separate functions.

The body functions do a lot of the same work as the header functions have already done, so is it possible to save the results of the header functions in a set of page level variables? (to avoid doing the same work twice).

Page level variables = variables with a page level scope that separate functions on the same page all have read/write access to.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is the normal behaviour of variables you define outside of any function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `global`, which is described on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Short example:

```
function do1()
{
    global $foo;
    $foo = do work ...
}

functio do2()
{
    global $foo;
    $bar = do work with ($foo); ...
}

do1();
do2();
```

And one word of adivce; be very careful not to accidentally reuse names for global variables.

Comment: Isn't global used across all pages? (just asking since I'm not used to do PHP)

Comment: @Louisa PHP scripts are fully terminated once a single page/item was delivered to the browser. Everytime you view one of your WP pages, the entire PHP code starts off from the top.

Comment: Ok. What about the call to "global $wpdb" that you see in many WP functions? Is there a db connection pool or similar somewhere, so creating new connections doesn't take a lot of time?

Comment: @Louisa It's quite possible that `$wpdb` already holds an active connection. I don't know anything about WP specifically, but there should be (googleable) documentation out there.